# MVC equivalent of [RequireHttps] in a .NET ASMX Webservice

Tags: c#, https, asmx

I've have to change a existing ASMX webservice so that all requests are made over HTTPS.  In MVC I could define the following which works fine;

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]
#endif
```

What is the equivalent for a .NET ASMX webservice, since I noticed that my ASMX project builds when I use the above code, but when I publish it I get

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RequireHttps' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I get around this problem ?